# Case-insensitive search on a postgres ArrayField with django

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

[In the Django documentation for ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-arrayfield), it lists a `contains` field lookup. However, no `icontains` (case insensitive lookup - many other fields have it) lookup is present in ArrayField.

I need a case-insensitive lookup function for ArrayField, similar to the pre-existing `contains` lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`icontains`, `iexact` are only applied on string type:

```
my_array_field__contains=['H']
```

> check if ['H'] is **included** in my_array_field

But if you try the following, it will works:

```
my_array_field__0__icontains='H'
```

> because it check if the first element **contains** H or h

Answer (score 8):

**warning:** this is a hack and led to a bug in my own app. Use at your own risk.

---

You can do a case-insensitive look-up using `icontains`, by omitting the square brackets you would use for `contains`:

```
queryset = my_model.objects.filter(field_name__icontains='my_substring')
```

This works because Postgres casts the ArrayField to text and then checks for 'my_substring' as a substring of the array's text representation. You can see this by examining the resulting query:

```
print(queryset.query)

# raw SQL output:
'SELECT ... WHERE UPPER("my_model"."field_name"::text) LIKE UPPER(%my_substring%)
```

This worked for me in Postgres 10.1.

---

**addendum/bug**

This approach caused a bug for my project. Say you want to check if the array field contains `'my_substring'`:

```
field_name__icontains='my_substring'
```

This will retrieve `'my_substring'`, but it will also retrieve `'foo_my_substring'`. This has to do with the string casting mentioned above. Use at your own risk.

Comment: I tried to query for gender with this and it returned both female with male lol

Comment: Be careful! This does not answer the original question, and as Stevula acknowledges at the end of his answer, it will indeed even cause a bug if the table has other strings containing the string you're looking for. @quick answer should be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can query case-insensive search for array like this:

```
select 'tartu' ILIKE ANY (array['Tallinn', 'Tartu','Narva']);
```

In Django:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(
    where=['%s ILIKE ANY (array_column_name)'],
    params=['tartu', ]
)
```